# Word list sources

Tags: language

I am looking for a source of nouns, adverbs, adjectives, and verbs in several languages.

I'd like the lists to *already* be split apart, and not have to go through the [OED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) (and non-English equivalents) by hand re-creating said lists.

I don't really care about definitions, and I understand some words can be multiple parts of speech - that's fine - words like "many" could be a noun or adjective, and can appear in both lists.

Does anyone here know of such a source? If not, might someone be able to point me in the right direction?

I'm ok with the format being any of the following (or similar if folks have ideas):

- csv: `<word>, noun (y/n), verb (y/n), adverb (y/n), adjective (y/n)`
- plaintext files like "nouns", "verbs", etc
- a mysql table
- etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667057/english-dictionary-as-txt-or-xml-file-with-support-of-synonyms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) from Princeton University for some projects. This is a lexical database in English. [Global WordNet](http://www.globalwordnet.org/) is an extension of the project trying to do the same for all languages.

You might also be interested in related projects at [http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/related-projects)

Comment: WordNet is the way to go.  All the top researchers use this.

Answer (score 5):

This may not help at all, I don't know. But MediaWiki has an [api](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query_-_Lists#categorymembers_.2F_cm) for listing all pages belonging to a certain category. You could try using it on Wiktionary.org.

Notes:

- Each query only returns 500 results. However, at the end, it also specifies a parameter to use in another query to get the next 500 results.
- It includes everything in the specified category, even other sub-categories.
- Results seem to be in alphabetical order, though everything starting with a capital letter comes before anything in lower case.

Examples:

- [First 500 page titles in the English Wiktionary in the cateogry "English nouns"](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=500&format=xml&cmtitle=Category:English%20nouns)
- [Continuing, using the parameter specified at the end of the previous query](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=500&format=xml&cmtitle=Category:English%20nouns&cmcontinue=Alan%20Whickers|)
- [First 500 page titles in the simple English Wiktionary in the category "Nouns"](http://simple.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=500&format=xml&cmtitle=Category:Nouns)
- [Again, continuing using the parameter specified at the end of the previous query](http://simple.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=500&format=xml&cmtitle=Category:Nouns&cmcontinue=Tulu|)

Hope this helps, it's what I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

I will second @teknikqa's suggestion of wordnet, but I would suggest you check out their APIs;

**STORYTIME**:
I had an AI course that had a language analysis part; I used the wordnet's perl API's to automatically lookup the top three definition types, and classify the phrasing from that in near-realtime
**END OF STORYTIME**

There are API's out there for [Lots of languages](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/related-projects)

FYI: The project got an A+